# How do you send pre-made Query object to NEST?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to write an api method that takes a generic Query built on the application level and send it to the elasticsearch database using the NEST interface.

The code for my routine is, so far:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Query")]
    public IEnumerable<Account> Query([FromBody]Object query)
    {
        IEnumerable<Account> result = null;
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
                            baseAddress
                            ).DefaultIndex("bank").InferMappingFor<Account>(m => m.IndexName("bank").TypeName("account"));
        var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor("bank").Mappings(ms => ms.Map<Account>(m => m.AutoMap()));
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        if (query == null)
        {
            var response = client.Search<Account>(s => s.Query(q => q.MatchAll()).Pretty().Size(1000));
            result = response.Documents;
        }
        else
            {
                var response = client.Search<Account>(s => s.Query(q => q.Raw(query.ToString())));
                result = response.Documents;
            }
        return result;
    }
```

I am using the sample database illustrated in Elastic at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_exploring_your_data.html.

The query I want to send is:

```
{
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "sort": [
    { "account_number": "asc" }
  ]
}
```

The routine delivers the right data when I send in a null for the query, but I want it to return any data when I send in a value for the query.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

What I am trying to do is create an api call interface where the query is constructed and sent to the api call to process it as a complete query with the api doing a generic call with a generic query object.

The current code (which works) is:

```
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> Query(Object query, String index)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> result = null;
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(baseAddress)
                            .DefaultIndex(index)
                            .InferMappingFor<T>(m => m.IndexName(index).TypeName(typeof(T).Name.ToLower()))
                             ;
        var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(index).Mappings(ms => ms.Map<T>(m => m.AutoMap()));
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        if (query == null)
        {
            var response = client.Search<T>(s => s.Query(q => q.MatchAll()).Pretty(true).Size(1000));
            if (response.IsValid)
            {
                result = response.Documents;
            }
            else
            {
                if (response.ServerError != null && response.ServerError.Error != null)
                    Logger.Logger.Warning(response.ServerError.Error.Reason);
                else if (response.OriginalException != null)
                    Logger.Logger.Error(response.OriginalException);
                else
                    Logger.Logger.Warning("NEST operation likely timed out.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var type = client.Infer.TypeName(TypeName.From<T>());
            var response = client.Search<T>(s => s.Query(q => q.Raw(query.ToString())).Pretty(true).Size(1000));
            if (response.IsValid)
            {
                result = response.Documents;
            }
            else
            {
                if (response.ServerError != null && response.ServerError.Error != null)
                    Logger.Logger.Warning(response.ServerError.Error.Reason);
                else if (response.OriginalException != null)
                    Logger.Logger.Error(response.OriginalException);
                else
                    Logger.Logger.Warning("NEST operation likely timed out.");
            }
        }
        client = null;
        return result;
    }
```

The query is constructed in another application and being sent to the Web API 2.x service.  The calling code currently is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(String query)
    {
        var client1 = new ElasticClient();
        var matchQuery = new SimpleQueryStringQuery()
        {
            AllFields = true,
            Analyzer = "standard",
            Boost = 1.1,
            Name = query,
            Query = query,
            DefaultOperator = Operator.Or,
            AnalyzeWildcard = true,
            Flags = SimpleQueryStringFlags.And | SimpleQueryStringFlags.Near | SimpleQueryStringFlags.Phrase,

        };
        String sqsq = client1.Serializer.SerializeToString(matchQuery);
        String queryString = String.Format("{{ \"simple_query_string\" : \r\n {0} \r\n}}", sqsq);
        var repository = new ElasticRepository();
        var studies = repository.Query(queryString);
        TempData["Studies"] = studies;
        TempData["Query"] = query;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

What I am looking for is a completely generic interface that sends a query created by the application and sent to it via a Web API 2.x call that interacts with the database directly.

I have attempted the suggestion in the answer below without success:  The elasticsearch database indicates something is wrong with the query as constructed.  It simply will not take the query object sent to it and return the same records as the NEST solution I already have.

It appears that the low-level elasticsearch.NET may be a more appropriate solution, however, I have been unable to get the query constructed to send it that it likes.

I am open to suggestions on this.

**UPDATE:**

I modified the api routine to implement the low level query for the generic query to:

```
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> Query(Object query, String index)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> result = null;
        var type = typeof(T).Name.ToLower();
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(baseAddress)
                            .DefaultIndex(index)
                            .InferMappingFor<T>(m => m.IndexName(index).TypeName(type))
                             ;
        var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(index).Mappings(ms => ms.Map<T>(m => m.AutoMap()));
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        if (query == null)
        {
            var response = client.Search<T>(s => s.Query(q => q.MatchAll()).Pretty(true).Size(1000));
            if (response.IsValid)
            {
                result = response.Documents;
            }
            else
            {
                if (response.ServerError != null && response.ServerError.Error != null)
                    Logger.Logger.Warning(response.ServerError.Error.Reason);
                else if (response.OriginalException != null)
                    Logger.Logger.Error(response.OriginalException);
                else
                    Logger.Logger.Warning("NEST operation likely timed out.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var response = client.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<T>>(index, type, query);

            if (response.Success)
            {
                var body = response.Body;
                if (body != null)
                {
                    result = body.Documents;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (response.ServerError != null && response.ServerError.Error != null)
                    {
                        Logger.Logger.Error(response.OriginalException);
                        Logger.Logger.Warning(response.ServerError.Error.Reason);
                        if (response.ServerError.Error.RootCause != null && response.ServerError.Error.RootCause.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var cause in response.ServerError.Error.RootCause)
                            {
                                Logger.Logger.Warning(String.Format("Root cause {0}:  {1}", cause.Index, cause.Reason));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (response.OriginalException != null)
                        Logger.Logger.Error(response.OriginalException);
                    else
                        Logger.Logger.Warning("ElasticSearch operation likely timed out.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (response.ServerError != null && response.ServerError.Error != null)
                {
                    Logger.Logger.Error(response.OriginalException);
                    Logger.Logger.Warning(response.ServerError.Error.Reason);
                    if (response.ServerError.Error.RootCause != null && response.ServerError.Error.RootCause.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var cause in response.ServerError.Error.RootCause)
                        {
                            Logger.Logger.Warning(String.Format("Root cause {0}:  {1}", cause.Index, cause.Reason));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (response.OriginalException != null)
                    Logger.Logger.Error(response.OriginalException);
                else
                    Logger.Logger.Warning("ElasticSearch operation likely timed out.");
            }
        }
        client = null;
        return result;
    }
```

This routine works with a properly-formed query string sent via a Web Api 2.x call.

The query itself that is formed at the web application level and sent to the web api is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(String query)
    {
        var client = new ElasticClient();
        var searchQuery = new
        {
            query = new
            {
                simple_query_string = new SimpleQueryStringQuery()
                {
                    AllFields = true,
                    Analyzer = "standard",
                    Boost = 1.1,
                    Name = query,
                    Query = query,
                    DefaultOperator = Operator.Or,
                    AnalyzeWildcard = true,
                    Flags = SimpleQueryStringFlags.And | SimpleQueryStringFlags.Near | SimpleQueryStringFlags.Phrase,
                }
            },
            sort = new List<ISort>() {
                new SortField() {
                    Field = Infer.Field("id"),
                    Order = SortOrder.Descending
                }
            }

        };
        String sqsq = client.Serializer.SerializeToString(searchQuery);
        var repository = new ElasticRepository();
        var studies = repository.Query(sqsq);
        TempData["Studies"] = studies;
        TempData["Query"] = query;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This routine still would not work because the sorting section was causing the following error:

> Root cause :  Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [id] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.

The cure for this was a command directly to the elasticsearch database.  This is:

```
PUT /studies/_mapping/study
{
  "properties": {
    "id": { 
        "type":     "text",
        "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping had to be changed to do any kind of sorting on any of the type fields.

The formatting of the search query combines the object initializer functions with the more generic object creation to provide the kind of abstraction I was looking for.

I think the problem I was attempting to address is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ["Raw" query in NEST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/raw-query-usage.html), you can only provide the query part of the request i.e. it cannot include `"sort"`or any other top level properties of the JSON object that would be provided to the `_search` API endpoint.

I think what you may be after here instead is to use the low level client to send the search request, but still return a strongly typed response of `SearchResponse<T>` as would be returned with using the high level client to make the search request.

The low level client is exposed on the high level client through the `.LowLevel` property; assuming the `Object query` coming in will be serialized as expected by JSON.Net, you could do

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .InferMappingFor<Account>(m => m.IndexName("bank").TypeName("account"))
        .DefaultIndex("default-index");

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    // query input to controller action
    var query = new
    {
        query = new { match_all = new { } },
        sort = new [] { new { account_number = "asc" } }
    };

    var index = client.Infer.IndexName(IndexName.From<Account>());
    var type = client.Infer.TypeName(TypeName.From<Account>());

    SearchResponse<Account> response = 
        client.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<Account>>(index, type, query).Body;
}

public class Account
{
}
```

Comment: I could not get any variation of this code to work with the object I send to the api interface above.  I think, however, that this is likely the approach I may want to take.  Currently, I don't need ordering or filtering with the search I am doing, but I may want to employ those in the future without creating an entirely new call.  In light of the edit above, can you suggest modifications to your answer?  It won't take the string I construct in the MVC application call and return any results.  It generates an error instead.

Comment: What version of NEST are you using? What version of Elasticsearch are you targeting? What's the error message returned from Elasticsearch when "it does not work"? What does the serialized query look like (you can see this with Fiddler): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/troubleshooting.html

Comment: 5.x on both versions.  The general error I was getting was "all shards failed" or something similar.  I checked the "root cause", and that told me (after I posted the earlier comment) that there was an indexing problem with using the fields for ascending/descending. As to sending a general query to the lowlevel interface, I believe I have that issue addressed.  I will post an update later on it.